# minimum of float in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++98

I want to get a minimum of float  without using
`std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest() [c++11]`

so I intend to do the following.
`-std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`
can I use it like this?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest says so, but I am not sure where the conclusion comes from.

Comment: Any IEEE-754 compliant floating point implementation has the sign as a separate bit (rather than encoded in two's or one's complement). That means negating the max is safe and correct

Comment: Is there a reason NOT to use standard C++ facilities? Getting the minimum of the maximum is probably not going to work anyway. I think at least to me your question does not make any sense (since you obviously can still use numeric limits)

Comment: @PepijnKramer The question is tagged c++98 so I assume they have to use an old compiler

Comment: For the record, every other floating point format I could find also uses a separate sign bit

Comment: In fact the standard claims that this is not always correct (https://eel.is/c++draft/support.limits#footnote-175), but I also don't know any case where it isn't.

Comment: Specifically the wording comes from [N2348](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2348.pdf) where it is noted that this is not guaranteed, but I do not not know whether it means that it isn't guaranteed by the specification or whether it means that there are floating point representations without that property in use. The first wording draft had it defined as `-max()`.

Comment: Standards can be wrong; it happens often.

Comment: @colon, "can I use it like this?" --> please append your reason for wanting this ability.

Comment: @Homer512 I was so surprised that everyone answered my first question sincerely. I'm admiring the coolness of stackoverflow while looking at the post with my friends. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `-std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`.  To make sure it is safe in the future, add a unit test to your project to confirm that `-std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is the same as `std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest()` for `float` and `double` (or whatever floating point types you are using).

If your `T` is actually some user- or library-defined type, it may not be safe to do this...but then your unit tests would flag it.

Comment: UV for "add a unit test to your project to confirm ..."